# fwrite append even the file position pointer is at the correct place

Tags: c

I want to overwrite an struct in a binary file. Here's my code 
:

```
struct my_st {
  char value[10];
};

void replace(char value[10]){
FILE *fpointer;
fpointer = fopen("data.dat", "rb+");
struct my_st x;
struct my_st new;
new.value="test";
while(1) {
 fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,fpointer);
 if(strcmp(x.value,value)==0)
   break;
}
  fwrite(&new,sizeof(x),1,fpointer);
}
```

I even check the place of file position pointer by printing it's value before fwrite and it was correct but it just append new data at the end of file and do not replace.

any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are you trying to replace the structure that was last read?

Comment: @kaylum yes I am.

Comment: Well, then your code is clearly wrong because the last `fread` will position the file pointer *after* that structure in the file.

Comment: Ok but it does not even change the next struct! It just append at the end.

Comment: @kaylum and another thing,so why printing of the struct value looks correct?(it's the value that I want change and not the next struct)

Comment: We can't verify that what you say is true. You need to provide the details of the test code or the log that you used to come to your conclusions. That is you still have not provided an MCVE - we need the code that calls `replace` as well as whatever code you used to validate the result.

Comment: "why printing of the struct value looks correct". Can't tell you. You did not show that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open a file for update (`+`) and if you do one or more read operations, you must do a positioning operation (e.g. `fseek()`) before you do any writes.  If you do one or more write operations, you must do a positioning operation (e.g. `rewind()`) before you do any reads.  See POSIX's specification of [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) for example.

> When a file is opened with update mode (`'+'` as the second or third character in the mode argument), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, the application shall ensure that output is not directly followed by input without an intervening call to `fflush()` or to a file positioning function (`fseek()`, `fsetpos()`, or `rewind()`), and input is not directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

You are doing no positioning operations between reads and writes.  That, in and of itself, leads to undefined behaviour.

Assuming your implementation exhibits 'undefined behaviour' by not going out of its way to misbehave, after your last `fread()`, you will write over the next entry — or append a new entry if the last one read was at the end of the file.

- Decide where you want the data written.
- Seek to the correct location (use `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR)` if you don't want to move the read/write pointer).
- Write.
- If you'll be reading next, do another seek — another no-op if need so be.