# Consecutive fwrite() not giving desired output

Tags: c

So I have the following code that I am toying around with:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

        FILE* fp;
        char c, currentchar;
        int flag = 0, count = 1;

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("wzip:insufficient args\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        while ( fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, fp) == 1) {
                if (flag == 1) {
                        if (c == currentchar) {
                                ++count;
                        }
                        else {
                                fwrite(&currentchar, sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
                                //printf("%d", count);
                                fwrite(&count, sizeof(int), 1, stdout);
                                currentchar = c;
                                count = 1;
                        }
                }
                if (flag == 0) {
                        currentchar = c;
                        flag = 1;
                }
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

The above code doesn't provide me the output from the second fwrite() function(that uses the count variable). I assume its a problem regarding stream flushing but I can't resolve it. Any help would be great!

E: for a sample input/output, suppose i have a file `test.1` that has the letters `sssaa` in it.

If I run `./wzip test.1` the output is:

`sa`

while ideally it should be:

`s3a2`

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: You write the raw binary representation of `count`, not its value in a printable form. If you want to write text, then use the proper text output functions (like e.g. `fprintf`).

Comment: `fwrite` can be used to display a single `char`, because a `char` is already encoded in a way that `stdout` understands. An `int` on the other hand needs to be converted to a string of digits before `stdout` can display it. That's what `printf("%d", count)` does. It converts the `int` to digit characters, and sends the digits to `stdout`.

Comment: Also `fwrite` is for file output, not terminal.

Comment: You can use `fprintf` for writing the integer to stdout.

Comment: I _want_ the output to be binary representation or I'll just use `printf()` (which I did to check if the value is printable and it _is_ printable).

Comment: Not sure but, I think you should use `fseek` before any `fread` and `fwrite`. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41668532/5322553

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

        FILE* fp;
        char c, currentchar;
        int flag = 0, count = 1;

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("wzip:insufficient args\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        while ( fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, fp) == 1) {
                if (flag == 1) {
                        if (c == currentchar) {
                                ++count;
                        }
                        else {
                                fwrite(&currentchar, sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
                                //printf("%d", count);
                                fprintf(stdout, "%i", count); /*  this one */
                                currentchar = c;
                                count = 1;
                        }
                }
                if (flag == 0) {
                        currentchar = c;
                        flag = 1;
                }
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Tested 'tcc'. Your fwrite(&count, sizeof(int), 1, stdout); write to stdout not '3' but 0x03 - see ANSII codes . You can check it if call with redirection and check output.file hexviewer. Something like 'wzip test.1 > out.txt'

Comment: I actually want to obtain the raw binary representation of `count`. It's the whole reason I'm using `fwrite()` in the first place. I believe `fprintf()` doesn't provide the same?

Comment: I think what OP wants is using `fwrite` specifically.

Comment: Yes @OzgurBagci is correct. I don't want a way of making this program work. I want to understand whats wrong with using `fwrite()` twice. Kindly refrain suggesting `printf()` and similar things. I am aware of how to get the thing done. I want to know how to get in dont using `fwrite()` i.e. preserving the binary form.

Comment: @Srijan-Sriv, you should convert binary value of 'int' ('short', 'char') to ascii representation. Use itoa() from stdlib.h or do it yourself. Also see 'stdlib' sources how it works in fprintf().